# Retrieving the only value from XML string

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here is a my XML string of datatype `nvarchar(MAX)`:

```
declare @string Nvarchar(MAX)
set @string='<ROOT><Data  C="1" /><Data  C="2" /><Data  C="3" /></ROOT>'
```

Expected result:

```
@c='1,2,3'

i want to check that the value of "C" is exists in table or not
```

Comment: You want to check if the value `1,2,3` exists as value in a `C` tag, right?

Comment: @gotqn yes,i stored that value in variable and later apply exists

Comment: The value of `@c` seems to be CSV. In the `XML` you have different values for the `C` tag. The desired output will be `1` as in the csv we have `1,2,3` and in the XML we have `1, 10, 20`, right?

Comment: sorry check the updated question, i receive value in int format in xml

Comment: pls. avoid using Nvarchar(MAX) when you are working with XML.

Comment: declare your @string variable as XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the values in tabular format:

```
declare @string Nvarchar(MAX)
set @string='<ROOT><Data  C="1" /><Data  C="2" /><Data  C="3" /></ROOT>'

DECLARE @StringXML XML = CAST(@string as XML);

SELECT T.c.value('(./@C)[1]', 'INT')
FROM @StringXML.nodes('ROOT/Data') T(c);
```

Then, you can apply the `EXIST` clause.

```
SELECT STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',' + T.c.value('(./@C)[1]', 'VARCHAR(12)')
        FROM @StringXML.nodes('ROOT/Data') T(c)
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1
    ,1
    ,''
);
```